# How can I ssh into a second server, run a command, and assign the output to a variable?

Tags: unix, ssh

This is what I am attempting to do:

```
fromServer=$(ssh -A first.com ssh second.com rpm -qa | grep exampleString)
echo $fromServer
```

echo does not print anything. If I manually shh into first and then ssh into second then run the command I get output:

```
ssh first.com
ssh second.com
rpm -qa | grep exampleString
```

How can I combine these three steps into one line and store the output into a variable?

Comment: note that your |grep is probably going to run on your originating server, NOT the ones you're sshing into.

Comment: You'll need to use quotes or some other technique to group your commands and distinguish hostname from command from parameter. What's the command passed to the first ssh? What's the command passed to the second? How do the respective shells figure that out?

Comment: 'ssh second.com rpm -qa | grep exampleString' or "ssh second.com rpm -qa | grep exampleString" did not seem to change the behavior. How else can I group the commands?

Comment: Your original command `ssh -A first.com ssh second.com rpm -qa | grep exampleString` looks like it ought to work, even if `grep` ends up running on a different host than `rpm`. The problem could just be that your grep pattern is wrong. Do you get expected output when you run `ssh -A first.com ssh second.com rpm -qa` without trying to grep or capture it into a variable? How about when you add the `| grep exampleString` part? What is "exampleString", ie what are you grepping for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use proper quoting or escaping:

```
fromServer=$(ssh -A first.com 'ssh second.com rpm -qa | grep exampleString')
echo $fromServer
```

or

```
fromServer=$(ssh -A first.com ssh second.com rpm -qa \| grep exampleString)
echo $fromServer

% VAR=$(ssh -C user@server ls -la \| grep vim)
% echo $VAR
-rw-------  1 user user      15153 Mar  22 13:45 .vimrc
```

---

edit: oooooooh, sneaky, I did not see you were doing **two** SSH ☺

So then you'll need a bit more quoting, because you don't want to have your pipe being interpreted by `first.com`. Here's three ways to work around that:

```
fromServer=$(ssh -A first.com ssh second.com rpm -qa \\\| grep exampleString)
fromServer=$(ssh -A first.com 'ssh second.com rpm -qa \| grep exampleString')
fromServer=$("ssh -A first.com 'ssh second.com rpm -qa | grep exampleString'")
```

What's happening is that you want to execute:

```
user@second % rpm -qa | grep exampleString
```

on the `second.com` server, so you have to escape the pipe so it's not interpreted by the `first.com` server:

```
user@first % ssh second.com rpm -qa \| grep exampleString
or
user@first % ssh second.com 'rpm -qa | grep exampleString'
```

but then again, you need to have that executed on `first.com`, from your local workstation, as you still don't want to see the pipe interpreted, you need to add a second layer of escaping/quoting:

```
user@workstation % ssh first.com "ssh second.com 'rpm -qa | grep exampleString'"
or
user@workstation % ssh first.com 'ssh second.com rpm -qa \| grep exampleString'
```

and then, once you're sure you get an output you can put that whole command's output in a variable:

```
VAR=$(ssh first.com "ssh second.com 'rpm -qa | grep exampleString'")
```

HTH

Comment: Adding the '' did not seem to change any behavior.

Comment: And the slash did not seem to do anything either.

Comment: Your issue is the pipe that you don't want to see interpreted in between your current workstation, and `second.com`'s host, which is why you need to quote twice the whole expression, or escape the pipe character twice using backslashes.

Comment: Just needed to add -t -t to second ssh.